# Regression from a varying number of variable sized sequences to a single scalar target

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

I have a recurrent network (currently a LSTM, but I may be switching to a recursive net to better reflect certain domain specific assumptions) for regression (to a single real valued scalar) on time series data, where certain labels have more than one data instance (sequence) associated with them.

To be more concrete, the sequences are measurements from an experiment, and the regression target is some scalar associated with the experiment. In each experiment I collect a different number of sequences, but the target is the same.

What would be a good way to model this? I assume adapting the RNN to be some kind of encoder that outputs a representation from a given sequence and then combines (averaging? using a learned function?) the different representations, feeding them into another network for the regression. Is anyone familiar with a work along these lines?